# Python - List comprehension break

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, break

I have the following list:

```
a = [[1,'abc',0],[1,'abc',2],[1,'abc',3],[2,'kak',0],[2,'kak',1],[2,'kak',2],[3,'kok,0]]
```

I want to create a list comprehension line that returns me the b list:

```
b = [[1,'abc',0],[2,'kak',0],[3,'kok',0]]
```

The list is created by unique values of the first column of entries of a.

I tried to do this:

```
aux1 = list(set([c[0] for c in a]))
b    = [[c for c in a break if c[0] == i] for i in aux1]
```

This code solves my problem, but not with list comprehension:

```
a = [[1,'abc',0],[1,'abc',2],[1,'abc',3],[2,'kak',0],[2,'kak',1],[2,'kak',2],[3,'kok',0]]

b = []

for aa in a:
    new = True
    for bb in b:        
        if bb[0]==aa[0]:
            new=False
            break
    if new:
        b.append(aa)
```

Comment: What are your conditions to get from `a` to `b`? You say unique values... do you mean just unique middle parts? Do you just want the first one in `a `that has the unique middle part (with index 1)?

Comment: I just want to remove the repetitive entries of a - which I mean the repetition of the first column of a. You are right, I just want the first one in a that has the unique middle part (with index 1)?

Comment: is the list `A` already sorted according to the first element in the inner list?

Comment: Yes, A is already sorted.

Comment: This makes what I want:

a = [[1,'abc',0],[1,'abc',2],[1,'abc',3],[2,'kak',0],[2,'kak',1],[2,'kak',2],[3,'kok',0]]
b = []
for aa in a:
    new = True
    for bb in b:        
        if bb[0]==aa[0]:
            new=False
            break
    if new:
        b.append(aa)

Comment: Why do you ask for a list comprehension?  Why not a readable, clear for loop instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not care about the second or third element in the inner list which is taken for the list `b` , you can use `itertools.groupby` as -

```
>>> b = [next(i) for x,i in groupby(sorted(a, key = lambda x: x[0]),lambda x: x[0])]
>>> b
[[1, 'abc', 0], [2, 'kak', 0], [3, 'kok', 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces the output that you're looking for:

```
a = [[1,'abc',0],[1,'abc',2],[1,'abc',3],[2,'kak',0],[2,'kak',1],[2,'kak',2],[3,'kok',0]]
b = list({x[0]:x for x in reversed(a)}.values())
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'abc', 0], [2, 'kak', 0], [3, 'kok', 0]]
```

Comment: Nice solution. Your third line can be written more simply as `b = list(temp.values())`. You could even leave out `temp` and just write `b = list({x[0]:x for x in reversed(a)}.values())`.

Comment: @flornquake - made the changes!